# AzureFileCopy task failing in YAML pipeline - works in Release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, winrm, azure-yaml-pipelines

I am trying to convert a release pipeline into a multi-stage YAML pipeline and I am running into an issue with the AzureFileCopy@4 task. When I run the task in a release pipeline, the task succeeds and files are copied to the remote VM.  When I run the task in a multi-stage YAML pipeline, the task fails.  Specifically, the following command within the task fails:

```
New-PSSession -ComputerName 'vmname.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com' -Port 5986 -Authentication Default -Name '68fe512f-477d-4d56-9217-5ab84517a53b' -Credential $credential -UseSSL -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' -ErrorVariable sessionErrors -ConfigurationName 'microsoft.powershell'
```

The error message that is generated is:

```
Connecting to remote server vmname.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com failed with the following error message : Access is denied.
```

I don't suspect a problem with the WinRM configuration, since I am connecting just fine in the Release Pipeline. Given the error and the command, I would say that it is the credentials, but I have looked at them over and over and they are exactly the same.

The inbound rules on the NSG have the WinRM port 5986 open to any source, so it doesn't appear that there is a restriction on which machines can start a new pssession.

**UPDATE** 12/22/20

Below is a sanitized version of the stage that is failing.  The filecopy mostly works when it is in my *build* stage, but not when it is part of a deployment stage using a *deploy* job

```
- stage: deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployR50
    displayName: Deploy R50 App
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    environment: 
      name: 'QA'
      resourceName: 'Test'
      resourceType: virtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureFileCopy@4
            inputs:
              SourcePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\R50\*'
              azureSubscription: 'Joe MSDN Azure'
              Destination: 'AzureVMs'
              storage: 'mytest'
              resourceGroup: 'TEST'
              MachineNames: 'Test'
              vmsAdminUserName: '***'
              vmsAdminPassword: $(VM_PASSWORD)
              TargetPath: 'c:\R50'
```

Comment: You can refer to the steps in the answer to check your yaml file.If it is not useful, please share the yaml code snippet you exported.  **Additional information:** In the release pipeline, it seems that the yaml file cannot be exported now. You could refer to this ticket: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1278001/view-yaml-doesnt-work-for-releases.html  could you share how you exported？Thanks

Comment: Hi @Joe Brinkman. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help.

Comment: I just saw your comments this morning, so I am working through and trying to rebuild the deployment part of the YAML from scratch again.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you can successfully run this task in the release pipeline, so the VM settings are correct.

Based on my test, I try to export the pipeline to Yaml and it still could work fine.

You can try the following steps to check your Yaml pipeline：

- When you export the Yaml file, you could directly upload the file to the repo instead of copying the code.

[image]

Then when you create the Yaml Pipeline, you could use the  **existing YAML file**.

- In the output yaml file, you need to check whether there are extra spaces or special characters.

This issue could be caused by incorrect username and password.

- You can try to manually re-add this task in the yaml pipeline and check if it could work.

Comment: I recreated the task using the Task assistant.  The username and password was entered using 1Password so I didn't accidentally mistype anything.

Comment: One difference between the Release and YAML is that I am using a Deployment job and an Environment with the YAML Pipeline, which I obviously don't use with the release.  I don't believe this is the issue, but I am still a little unclear on whether these might be impacting the task.  I may try moving the task into "build" stage and removing the deployment stage/job to see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks for your information.You can check if it could work in the build job. On the other hand, since you are using the environment, do you mean that you are running the pipeline on `Environment-> Virtual Machine`?  Or you are running the pipeline on Microsoft-Hosted agent

Comment: I have an Environment, and am trying to do a deployment to the VM in that environment using a Deployment job as part of a multi-stage pipeline.  When the CopyFile task is in that Deployment job, it is failing. When I move it to the main build stage and remove the deployment stage, then the creation of the new-pssession succeeds. So it looks like something about running the AzureFileCopy task in the context of the Deployment job is causing the issue.

Comment: In this case, this issue is related with the environment. In Release Pipeline, are you using the deployment group or Agent Job ? Can you connect the Azure Vm on the Virtual Machine?  You may try to use the  AzureFileCopy@3 task and check if there are the firewalls in the virtual machine.

Comment: I added some clarifying comments and the relevant YAML section to the original description.  The release pipeline is using an Agent Job.  Yes. I can connect to the Azure VM.  I will try the AFC@3 and see if that resolves anything.

Comment: Thanks for your update. You could also try to set the `Domain/UserName` in the Username field. In addition, your yaml code could be correct.

Comment: The 'Domain\UserName' was already tried and it didn't change anything.

Comment: If you use the Azure file copy version 3 , will it work or still have the same issue. Here is a doc about the azure file copy version 3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy-version3?view=azure-devops This version has different configuration